# How to split bootstrap 4 table header column?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, tablecell

I am learning frontend where I am trying to design table. where I want to merge multiple column in single column by dividing into cell like there is bootstrap classes `colspan` and `rowspan` but I am unable to design exactly what I am looking for here I am attching image for which I am trying to design. Can someone please guide me how can I design that table.

Here is table which I trying to desing.[image]

any help will be appreciated thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2"></th>
    <th></th>
    <th rowspan="2"></th>
    <th colspan="2"></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="2"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks for reply, Can you just give one simple example.

Comment: Meherdip I am unable to understand your code it will be great-full if you simply put some values in that table like column name and there values.

Comment: I have run that code its looking something like that what i am looking for but if you make it proper like give theader tbody then th td and some values then it will be easy to readable.